# Tooltips in DC.js ( D3 Library )

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

DC.js has great functionality built-in to display tooltips per [documentation](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/master/web/docs/api-latest.md) `.title([titleFunction])` function.

Is there anyway to make the tooltips more like a bootstrap style tooltip similar to [rickshaw's implementation](http://code.shutterstock.com/rickshaw/examples/extensions.html)?

[image]

Comment: D3-tip can indeed be used to replace the dc.js titles, what's the problem?

Comment: I just found that and added it to the comment :)

Comment: Post your answer and it may be helpful for others too.

Comment: There's nothing added to the comment, I'm trying to figure out this one too.

Comment: Answer the question or delete it.